# Connecting Eclipse Ditto and Eclipse Hono

Tags: eclipse-hono, eclipse-ditto, eclipse-iot, eclipse-digital-twin

I am trying to do the steps stated in https://www.eclipse.org/ditto/2018-05-02-connecting-ditto-hono.html#create-a-connection-to-hono to connect Ditto and Hono. I have tested Ditto and Hono with the steps explained "Hello World" for Ditto and "Getting Started" for Hono. I have created a tenant as explained in the Getting Started part but when I tried to do it for the example in the given link, I get Could not resolve host: hono.eclipse.org response.

What is the reason of this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Did you see the red warning on top of the 4 years old blog post that this guide no longer works with the current versions of Eclipse Hono and Eclipse Ditto?

[image: Warning]

I would suggest to follow the link of that warning and follow the instructions of the Eclipse IoT Packages project.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually I realized the warning but I forgot to remove the question. Sorry for this.